# Calling pipenv in CMake command ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, cmake, pipenv

I am trying to generate C/C++ source files via a Python script using CMake, but am running into an issue where it appears that [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) is not working as expected.

I've attempted to create a simplified version of my real world example [on my Github](https://github.com/erichschroeter/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/tree/master/Python_example).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)
project(example)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED)
find_program(PipEnv pipenv REQUIRED)

# Create command to compile the generate command
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py
    COMMAND ${PipEnv} install
    COMMENT "Installing pipenv dependencies [${PipEnv} install]"
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Pipfile
)

add_custom_target(
    generate_version
    COMMAND ${PipEnv} run ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py -o src/version.h config.json
    COMMENT "Generating version header [${PipEnv} run ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py -o src/version.h config.json]"
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config.json
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
[main] Building folder: Python_example 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /maxcpucount:10
[build] CMake is re-running because C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is out-of-date.
[build]   the file 'C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/CMakeLists.txt'
[build]   is newer than 'C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.depend'
[build]   result='-1'
[build] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
[build] -- Configuring done
[build] -- Generating done
[build] -- Build files have been written to: C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/build
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.2+e481bbf88 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   Checking Build System
[build]   Generating version header [C:/Program Files/Python38/Scripts/pipenv.exe run C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/generate.py -o src/version.h config.json]
[build]   Traceback (most recent call last):
[build]     File "C:/src/cmake-auto-increment-build-number/Python_example/generate.py", line 14, in <module>
[build]       from docopt import docopt
[build]   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(230,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\src\cmake-auto-increment-build-number\Python_example\build\generate_version.vcxproj]
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing the `COMMAND` arg for `add_custom_target()` to `${PipEnv} install`, but that had no effect. Is there something else I need to be passing to pipenv or the CMake command to get this working?

Comment: your repo already contain a generate.py so your `pyenv install`  in add_custom_command() won't be run (output already here)

Comment: Also you should REALLY create your pyenv in a binary dir IMHO

Comment: If I change the `add_custom_command`'s `OUTPUT` to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.h` and the `add_custom_target`'s `DEPENDS` to include `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/version.h` I can get the custom command to run, but I still run into the ModuleNotFoundError as if pipenv isn't even being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of errors here...

1. Your custom command output and depends of the same file, generate.py
   note: you can see a make error in the trace
2. By default add_custom_command will the current source dir as working directy while custom target is run in the current build dir.
   i.e. both are running in different directory -> two different pipenv used...
3. You muse use `pipenv run python` instead of `pipenv run ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}`...
4. here my Dockerfile to run some tests

```
# Create a virtual environment with all tools installed
# ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu
FROM ubuntu:rolling AS base
LABEL maintainer="mizux.dev@gmail.com"
# Install system build dependencies
ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -yq git wget build-essential \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install CMake 3.18.1
RUN wget "https://cmake.org/files/v3.18/cmake-3.18.1-Linux-x86_64.sh" \
&& chmod a+x cmake-3.18.1-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&& ./cmake-3.18.1-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/usr/local/ --skip-license \
&& rm cmake-3.18.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
CMD [ "/usr/bin/bash" ]

# Install Python 3.8
RUN apt-get update -qq \
&& apt-get install -yq python3-dev python3-pip \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
# Install pipenv
RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv

FROM base AS devel
WORKDIR /home/sample
COPY . .

FROM devel AS build
RUN cmake -S. -Bbuild
RUN cmake --build build --target all -v
```

To Build:

```sh
docker build --target=build --tag so .
```

To Play (i.e. stop a devel stage then spawn a container to play):

```sh
docker build --target=devel --tag so .
docker run --rm -it so
```

So you modified CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5)
project(example)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter REQUIRED)
find_program(PipEnv pipenv REQUIRED)

# Create command to compile the generate command
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT Pipfile.lock
    COMMAND pwd
    COMMAND ${PipEnv} install
    COMMENT "Installing pipenv dependencies [${PipEnv} install]"
    DEPENDS
        Pipfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    generate_version
    COMMAND pwd
    COMMAND ${PipEnv} run python generate.py -o src/version.h config.json
    COMMENT "Generating version header [${PipEnv} run ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/generate.py -o src/version.h config.json]"
    DEPENDS
        Pipfile.lock
        generate.py
        config.json
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I didn't realize about the different working directories. btw, you don't need (and shouldn't) include the `COMMAND ${PipEnv} run ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -m pip install docopt` in your `add_custom_command` since that's the whole point of using pipenv to install the dependencies.

Comment: actually it was not working here ^^;, it seems you need to use `pipenv run python` instead of `pipenv run ${Python3_EXECUTABLE}`

Comment: But doesn't that use the python on your system PATH (which _could_ be python 2), whereas using `${Python3_EXECUTABLE}` will use whichever python version CMake finds and is guaranteed to be python version 3+?

Comment: Frankly, i don't know, but since your Pipfile contains explicitly python 3.8..., BTW pipenv install also have an option `--python` but again since I don't use it, doc is sparse so I won't dig further, BTW venv/pyenv is largely enough to my use case ;)
Also i don't know where the pipenv is located as well as its site-package...